# VBscript regular expression for 'Not having a particular word"

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to write regular expression for not having the word `Regular` in the sentence.

Sentence:

```
c= "Regular Expression should not be present".
```

My code:

```
RegularExpressionObject.IgnoreCase = True
RegularExpressionObject.Global = True
RegularExpressionObject.Pattern = "(Regular){0}"  ' this is to make sure the word "Regular" is not 'available
Set Matches3 = RegularExpressionObject.Execute(c)
If (Matches3.Count = 0) Then
    MsgBox ("Regular Expression do not match")
Else
    MsgBox ("they match")
End If
```

I am not able to succeed, could anybody please help me by correcting pattern as per my need.

Comment: Do you want to check only the characters `Regular`? What I mean by that is for example, should `Regularity` cause the match to fail too?

Comment: Thanks Jerry, for your reply.

You are correct, if sentence has text 'Regular' should fail. It meanse 'Regularity' should fail too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the match to fail on the characters `Regular` (i.e. it should fail for `Regularity` as well), then your regex shouldn't have `{0}`. You can actually simply use:

```
c = "Regular Expression should not be present"
If (InStr(c,"Regular") > 0) Then
    MsgBox ("'Regular' is in c")
Else
    MsgBox ("'Regular' is not in c")
End If
```

That is, you don't really need a regex for that.

Well, if you want a regex solution, I guess you could try something like this:

```
RegularExpressionObject.IgnoreCase = True
RegularExpressionObject.Global = True
RegularExpressionObject.Pattern = "Regular"
Set Matches3 = RegularExpressionObject.Execute(c)
If (Matches3.Count = 0) Then
    MsgBox ("'Regular' is not in c")
Else
    MsgBox ("'Regular' is in c")
End If
```

Which I think is closer to what you were attempting. If `Regular` matches, then say that it's present in the string.

Comment: Hey Thanks Jerry for the solution. But there is something else i was looking at, is there anything in Regular Expreession(vbscript) patttern which will accept "Not(String)". 

Here wanted to understand is, can we use 'Not' or '!' symbols.. i am assuming.. which will work as Not operator.

Comment: @Srekk Yes, there's one but it's not as easy to grasp if you're not familiar with regex. But since you ask :) You can use a negative lookahead this way, with a beginning of line anchor: `^(?!.*Regular)`. It's imperative to lock it and use `.*` so that the check is done only once (otherwise, the script will take very long to complete the validation). Something else is that a negative lookahead is a zero-width assertion; it doesn't consume any characters; for instance, if you print the matches with the above regex, you will get an empty string.

Comment: Nice explanation @Jerry. BTW, in VBScript you can use `RegularExpression.Test(string)` to evaluate if a regex matches or not. It returns a boolean and is more clear if you don't need the Matches object.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Awesome! I actually don't know much about VBScript ^^; I know regexes, but I found that's a nice way to learn tid bits of other languages when answering on here and here's a nice example :)

Comment: @AutomatedChaos. Thats really Awesome. You guys made my day. Loving this site. :) :)