# in vbscript an Error when using Regexp.Execute

Tags: vbscript

In vbscript while using regular expression EXECUTE function, when there is a match the program proceeds, but when there is no match than the program throws an error and crashes. Is there a way of fixing this, a workaround ? Thanks in advance.

```
dim object_str : object_str = "cup of tea"

Set compare_exp = new RegExp
compare_exp.IgnoreCase = False
compare_exp.Global = True
compare_exp.Pattern = "tea1"

wscript.echo compare_exp.Execute(object_str).Item(0).Value
wscript.echo "continue"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBscript regular expression for 'Not having a particular word"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22526480)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the regex found a match before attempting to read the results:

```
dim object_str : object_str = "cup of tea"

Set compare_exp = new RegExp
compare_exp.IgnoreCase = False
compare_exp.Global = True
compare_exp.Pattern = "tea1"

dim result: set result = compare_exp.Execute(object_str)
if result.count > 0 then
    wscript.echo result.Item(0).Value
else
    wscript.echo "no match"
end if
```

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help. The missing piece was SET result.